# PHP Sleeping Infinite While Loop

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, sleep

What am I doing wrong here? Am I missing how while loops work in PHP? I want this to keep looping in the background on the server even after the page is closed.

**Important note: It doesn't work even if I keep the page open.**

I feel like theres an obvious syntactical error I'm making with PHP.

```
        ignore_user_abort(true);
        set_time_limit(0);

        while(1){
            $dbConnection = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); 
            $query = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE email = '$user_email'";
            $id = mysqli_query($dbConnection, $query);
            $idrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($id);
            $result = $idrow['user_id'];

            $querydata1 = "SELECT data1 FROM queue WHERE user_id = '$result'";
            $data1 = mysqli_query($dbConnection, $querydata1);
            $data1row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data1);
            $resultdata1 = $data1row['data1'];

            if($resultdata1 != NULL){
                $querydata2 = "SELECT data2 FROM queue WHERE user_id = '$result'";
                $data2 = mysqli_query($dbConnection, $querydata2);
                $data2row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data2);
                $resultdata2 = $data2row['data2'];

                include 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

                $mail = new PHPMailer;

                $mail->isSMTP();
                $mail->Host = 'smtp.mandrillapp.com';
                $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
                $mail->Username = 'username';
                $mail->Password = 'password';
                $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
                $mail->Port = 587;

                $mail->From = 'test@test.com';
                $mail->FromName = 'test';
                $mail->addAddress($user_email);

                $mail->Subject = 'Test';
                $mail->Body = "$resultdata2"; 

                $mail->send();

            } else {
                break;
            }

            time_sleep_until(microtime(true)+10);
        }
```

Hey guys, I'm back again!

So, what I want to code to do is:

1. Take user input
2. Query database using user input
3. Email the results every 60 seconds.

My solution was to put the last two stages in a while loop and then making the script sleep for 60 seconds at the end.

The result: I get one email, with the useful data.

Comment: it doesn't work at all, or it runs for a while and then stops? if you are on a shared hosting, it's likely that the provider has a script that checks for long-running scripts and kills them

Comment: how do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: is safe mode on?  "Warning
This function has no effect when PHP is running in safe mode. There is no workaround other than turning off safe mode or changing the time limit in the php.ini." http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: You want to send an email every 10 seconds? Em...

Comment: Sorry about the misspelling, clearly rushing too much today.     I know it doesn't work because I'm testing the emailing against myself and I don't get more than one email, meaning the script doesn't execute more than once. And hypothetically, 10 seconds. The 10 seconds was just a trivial number for testing.

Comment: the problem may be elsewhere then. Plus, you may want to look into using a cron job instead, if you want to run your code at the same intervals.

Comment: Surely this approach should work though, right?

Comment: Where is the code for the email and such?  Do you need to run this from a web page or can you just execute it via CLI?

Comment: I'll add that in if you wish, wait there, should be up in a few minutes. I need to start this running from a web page, once the user has input information and then it to continue running even after the user has left the page. I know that's a strange request.

Comment: Use @Devon otherwise I won't see your message.  What happens in the event that one user, or multiple users, access this page multiple times?  Do you have anything preventing this from being run hundreds of times and bringing down your server?

Comment: That'll be the next step @Devon, it's on the to-do list ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- duplicity solved.  ( I think )

Answer (score 0):

Most servers have a time limit execution for php scripts. in most cases a script will only run for 30 seconds before timing out. If you have access to to the server configuration you can change this to infinite.

`Set_time_limit(0)` sometimes doesn't work depending on the server configuration. A while back I tried the same thing and nothing, but changing the settings in the server did it for me.

> Edit

Due to complains that changing the default settings on your server could create a security risk you can do something different. Looking at your comments you want to query for data and then email said mention data.

You can do this very easily by creating a stand alone php script (not while loop) that follows your logic one time. Using Jquery you can call this script as many times and as often as you want when a webpage is loaded.

To make this script run on the background without user interaction you want to create a cronjob that calls this script every so often (you can define the time interval).

Comment: You did see the `set_time_limit(0);` in the question?

Comment: @arkascha some times that function doesn't work depending on the server configuration. A while back I tried the same thing and nothing, but changing the settings in the server did it for me.

Comment: Then you should write that in your answer. Especially since you mention to change something using administrative rights. Generally changing this in the php configuration would be a huge security issue you create. So a really bad advice. If you have administrative rights, then you should advise how to change the configuration such that this command has effect.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your use of `break`.  When you don't have data in your queue, you issue a break.  This will close your loop, and thus end the execution of your script.

`continue` would be the logical thing here to continue to the next iteration of the loop, but that would also skip the sleep at the bottom of the loop.  Therefore, I don't think there is any need for the `else{}` block at the end of your loop.  Just let it hit the sleep section and continue the loop as normal if the data is NULL.

---

P.S.  why not just do one query with:

```
$querydata = "SELECT data1,data2 FROM queue WHERE user_id = '$result'";
```

Seems redundant to do two queries back to back with the same params just to get two different columns.

Comment: let's see what the OP has to say. Wishing they'd of posted their full code in the first place.

Comment: Fred, come on, lay off. I'm just looking for a little help. You're being overly unwelcoming.

Comment: @Devon, I took away the else{} block, it still doesn't work, strange.

Comment: @gregjw, and it sends the first email?  Does the execution stop after ~10 seconds or longer?

Comment: @Devon It sends the first email, but there's nothing else after that.

Comment: @gregjw we're supposed to guess what you were using for code? Your original post never contained the word "break", so as for the "lay off", you didn't help us, help you in the first place. I/we see tons of unclear questions day in and day out, where they end up getting closed as unclear. We enjoy helping, but when we don't know what we're dealing with, people run off. Would you like to buy a pair of shoes you never saw or tried on, only ending up they didn't fit and hurt you? I think I've made my point.

Comment: It did, in the comments filled with pseudocode. As someone so prolific in the community, I'd expect you to be more friendly and less combative.

Comment: @gregjw Fred is right.  I'm probably going above and beyond what anyone else would expect at Stackoverflow here.    As for your script, add some debugging arguments, echo to keep track of how many times the loop is run, see the last output to know when the loop quits, make sure you have error_reporting(E_ALL) and display_errors on.